Is this sequence (involving a quadratic form) a martingale difference sequence?
Let $\mathcal{X}=\left\{ \mathbf{x}_{n},1\leq n\leq N\right\} $ be
a collection of i.i.d. random vectors, where $\mathbf{x}_{n}=\left(x_{n,1},\dots,x_{n,M}\right)^{\prime}$
has real i.i.d entries, $\mathrm{E}\left[x_{n,m}\right]=0$, $\mathrm{E}\left[x_{n,m}^{2}\right]=1$,
and $\mathrm{E}\left[x_{n,m}^{4}\right]$ is finite. Let $\left\{ \mathbf{A}_{(n)},1\leq n\leq N\right\} $
be a collection of random symmetric PSD matrices where $\mathbf{A}_{(n)}$
depends on all elements of $\mathcal{X}$, except for $\mathbf{x}_{n}$.
Denote by $\mathcal{F}_{n}$ the $\sigma$-field generated by $\left\{ \mathbf{x}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{x}_{n}\right\} $ and let
$$
\eta_{n}=\mathbf{x}_{n}^{\prime}\mathbf{A}_{(n)}\mathbf{x}_{n}-\mathrm{tr}\left(\mathbf{A}_{(n)}\right),\quad n=1,\dots,N.
$$
In the proof of Lemma 4 from this this paper, the authors claim that $\left\{ \eta_{n},1\leq n\leq N\right\} $
forms a martingale difference sequence with respect to the filtration
$\left\{ \mathcal{F}_{n},1\leq n\leq N\right\} $. Is this really
the case?
It is indeed true that
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]=0.
$$
But I don't think we have the key m.d.s. property that
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}\eta_{n-1}\right]=0,
$$
since
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}\eta_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]\right]\neq\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n-1}\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1}\right]\right].
$$
Consequentially, Burkholder's inequality (which the authors use in the
proof of Lemma 4) does not appear to hold. E.g., for $p=2$,
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\eta_{n}\right)^2\right]\neq\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}^{2}\right].
$$
Is my conjecture right that $\left\{ \eta_{n},1\leq n\leq N\right\} $
is not an m.d.s.? If so, does it constitute some other type of known  sequence
(with perhaps some interesting properties)?

Maybe naive, but the definition of an MDS doesn't seem to require independence of neighboring instances of the random variables.

The instances of an m.d.s are indeed not independent of each other, but the covariances should be zero: $\mathrm{E}\left[\eta_{n}\eta_{n-j}\right]=0$ for all $j \neq 0$. In my question $j=1$, but could have extended it to other $j$.

It seems that in this context, we indeed have $\mathbb E\left[\eta_n\mid\mathcal F_{n-1}\right]=0$ but a important requirement for having a martingale difference sequence is that $\eta_n$ should be $\mathcal F_n$-measurable, which does not seem to be the case. For example, if $\mathbf{A}_{n}=x_{N,M}I_m$ for $n<N$ and $\mathbf{A}_{N}=0$, then $\{\mathbf{A}_{n},1\leq n\leq N\}$ follows the requirements, but in this case, for
$n<N$,
$$
\eta_n=x_{N,M}\sum_{k=1}^Mx_{n,k}^2-x_{N,M}
$$
hence $\mathbb E\left[\eta_n\mid\mathcal F_n\right]=0$.
The argument proposed by the authors would have worked fine if
$\mathbf{A}_n$ was a function of $\mathbf{x}_1,\dots, \mathbf{x}_{n-1}$.
I do not know whether it is was is needed in the paper.

That is what I thought, that the sequence is not adapted to the filtration. This would invalidate the remainder of the proof of that lemma (except for when $\mathbf{A}_{(n)}$ would be nonrandom or have a dependence structure like you mention).

Yes. It seems that the authors are still active in research, so you can maybe write them for clarifications.
